# Prompting user to select text file from get external data

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that uses the get external data option to import a text file.  Is there a way that I can prompt the user to select a file in this code or should I take a different approach?  I like this approach because I can exclude some columns during the import, but I am open to other options.

```
With Sheets(1).QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\Program Files\SubDirectory\ThisIsMyFile.txt" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "ThisIsMyFile"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(9, 9, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 9, 9, 2, 9, 9, 9, 2, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, _
        9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 9, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2 _
        , 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 2, 9, 9, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 9, 9, _
        2, 9, 9, 2, 2, 2)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```

Thanks in advance!

Thanks for the help.  I got this code to work:

```
  Dim FileFilter As String
  Dim Filename As String
  Dim SrcWkb As Workbook
  MsgBox "Select file"
  FileFilter = "Text Files (*.txt), *.txt"
  Filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter, 1)

    If Filename = "False" Then Exit Sub
With Sheets(1).QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & Filename, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = Filename
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(9, 9, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 9, 9, 2, 9, 9, 9, 2, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, _
        9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 9, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2 _
        , 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 2, 9, 9, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 9, 9, _
        2, 9, 9, 2, 2, 2)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
Sub FileName()

fileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")

If fileToOpen <> False Then QueryTable fileToOpen

End Sub

Sub QueryTable(file As String)

With Sheets(1).QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & file, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "ThisIsMyFile"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(9, 9, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 9, 9, 2, 9, 9, 9, 2, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, _
        9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 9, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2 _
        , 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 2, 9, 9, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 9, 9, _
        2, 9, 9, 2, 2, 2)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```