# Macro to paste text open file

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below macro that imports External Data From Text, sets the text to column by comma, and sets all columns to text. I'd like to modify the below so it opens a message box, prompts to open a file, and follows the procedure. Right now it's using the file path and name I had recorded from.

```
Cells.Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
    Range("A1").Select
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\------\FAC\FAC010515.txt", Destination:=Range( _
        "$A$1"))
        .Name = "FAC010515"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```

Comment: Found the answer here:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12515896/prompting-user-to-select-text-file-from-get-external-data][1]

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution from here: [Link](http://software-solutions-online.com/2014/03/11/excel-vba-open-file-dialog/)

```
Dim intChoice As Integer 
Dim strPath As String 

'only allow the user to select one file 
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False
'make the file dialog visible to the user 
intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show
'determine what choice the user made 
If intChoice <> 0 Then 
'get the file path selected by the user 
strPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this fits with my above code. I need to modify rows 5 and 7 so they are variable and dependent on a prompt to open a file.

Comment: @Dimitri since it is a working solution and the only answer, however it would be nice to check this answer as a solution...